# Which table does COUNT(*) refer to if I'm joining tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have this code:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, w.channel, COUNT(*) num
FROM accounts a
JOIN web_events w
ON a.id = w.account_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, w.channel
ORDER BY num;
```

Which number of rows will the function `COUNT(*)` actually return?

I am guessing it should return the number of all the records (rows) in the accounts table, but it seems to not be the case.

Comment: The number of rows of each group of a.id, a.name, w.channel. This is the purpose of `GROUP BY a.id, a.name, w.channel`.

Answer (score 1):

You have used both `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`. The `GROUP BY` clause groups all records for each account and channel and the `COUNT()` function in conjunction with `GROUP BY` counts the number of events for each account.

Comment: what would it return in case i didn't use it in conjunction with the GROUP BY clause ?

Answer (score 0):

It will return number of each group - a.id, a.name, w.channel

Comment: so for each group of a.id, a.name, w.channel, it will return the number of times a combination of the three columns repeats itself, right ?

Comment: so the GROUP BY clause kinda create a sub-table of each group, and when COUNT(*) is used in this case it returns the number of rows of each sub-table, right ? (just making sure i got this right)

Comment: Well, if you use count without grouping it will return number all all rows from your select statement. When you use group by with count - it will count each group.
https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-group-by.php - here is maybe more official explanation :)